# Multiple configuration for same environment in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I currently have a spring boot app.

application.yml

application-dev.yml

In application.yml i have

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
```

Now i have multiple configurations for dev provile eg. say dev-1,dev-2 and dev-3

How can i configure it ?Any best or standard way of doing it?I am on 2.3.4 spring boot version

Comment: What about having multiple profiles like dev-1, dev-2 etc?

Comment: yes that will  work..but i don't know if thats the standard way.Maybe spring cloud config

Comment: As @Ikamal mentioned you can make your own same env naming convention. It should be somethning related to the difference.

Comment: i know that solution but do you think usingspring cloud config is better?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate profiles via commas, like

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev, dev-1
```

but if you want to add specific properties and not override them, as `The spring.profiles.active property follows the same ordering rules as other properties, the highest PropertySource will win` , you can use include

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
    include:
      - dev-1
```

for more, see[documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-adding-active-profiles)